How to create a WTPART using jax web service in windchill PDM link
I'm trying to create a WTPart or WTDocument using jax web service. Please help me if anyone knows it
I have created a web service extends with Jax web service, and I'm passing name and number as a web param. While compiling service class only error is persisting
